# Does the Android Build class information ever change?

Tags: android

I am hoping to implement some security for an Android app to prevent people from using the code unless it was installed on the correct device by the company. My first choice would be to make sure the app was installed through the Google Play Store, but this app will not be available there.

I have determined that one security measure that will work for my use case is checking some of the information in the [Build class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build). I am concerned that there could be the possibility that some of the fields in the class may not stay the same, even if the same model of device is always used.

What portions of the Build class are subject to change for a specific model of device and what fields should never change?

Comment: You mean change at run time or during releases?

Comment: I mean during releases. For example, could a Lenovo Tab 3 8 go through different stages after release when it has different data in the various fields of the Build class?

I want to make sure I am using fields that are going to be unique to the type of device used, but will also not change once the device is released to the public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end all of these system configs are just .xml files residing on the device somewhere around /data/system/sysconfig which you can modify in any way you want if you have write access (aka root) so I would recommend starting from making sure that the user running your app does not have root privileges. There are some FOSS libraries for it, you can start from there.